# How are で and いう being used in this context?

Tags: grammar, meaning

There are a few things that I don't understand about the highlighted text in the image below. The biggest question I have is what **でいう** is doing after **人間** (is it some sort of construction or are they acting as two completely seperate words?) and what **で** is doing after **程度**. Also at the end where it says 「**という元気なキャラクターだ。**」who is that referring to?

I also found [this](https://eikaiwa.dmm.com/uknow/questions/32991/) page which describes ～で言うところの but I'm not sure if that's related.

[image]

> 設定年齢は人間でいう１３歳程度で、桜井氏いわく「悩みません。あと自分探しとかもしません（笑）」という元気なキャラクターだ。

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`AでいうB` means "(equivalent of) B in A's terms" or "known as B in A".

- 彼は人間でいう13歳程度だ。
  He is about 13 years old in human years.
- 彼は今でいう糖尿病だった。
  He had a disease now known as diabetes.
- ロシアのKGBはアメリカでいうCIAだ。
  KGB in Russia is comparable to CIA in the US.

で after 程度 is simply the te-form of だ, and it's used to connect two sentences. 元気なキャラクター refers to Pit, and 桜井氏いわく～という modifies 元気なキャラクター.

> 設定年齢は人間でいう13歳程度**で**、
>   The age (of Pit) is (set to) about 13 in human years, **and** ...
>
> 桜井氏いわく「悩みません。あと自分探しとかもしません(笑)」という元気なキャラクターだ。
>   he (=Pit) is a cheerful character who, according to Mr. Sakurai, "doesn't worry, and doesn't go on a journey of self-discovery :D".